# How to source file.R without output

Tags: r

Is it possible to source a file without printing all the charts etc (already tried with echo=F)?

In my case I call the png("filename%03d.png") device early in the script. It is not to big a hassle to comment this out - but all the charts do take a lot of time to render. (the specific file I am working with now uses base-graphics - but mostly I'll be using ggplot2 - which makes the issue somewhat more important (ggplot2 is excellent, but in the current implementation not the fastest))

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best sounding solution, but If you might be running this script often like this, you could declare a boolean whether graphics are required (graphics_required=TRUE) and then enclose all your plot commands in if/then clauses based on your boolean, then just change the boolean to change the behaviour of the script

Comment: Thank you all who answered this question. I think the boolean approach is what comes closest. Thank you all - and especially PaulHurleyuk

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem for ggplot2 or lattice graphics - you always have to explicitly `print` them when they are called in non-interactive settings (like from within a script).

Comment: But if i have a script with lots of print (plot) - is there a way to source the file without the print statements? 

Maybe the best way to do this would be to have separate scripts for plots and for other data mingling.

Comment: Yes, define a boolean toggle variable and the decide to print/not to print.

Answer (score 2):

Good practise for coding R means wrapping as much of your code as possible into functions.  (See, e.g., Chapter 5 of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), pdf.)  If you place your plotting code inside a function, it need not be displayed when you source it.  Compare the following.

File foo.r contains

```
plot(1:10)
```

When you call `source('foo.r')`, the plot is shown.

File bar.r contains

```
bar <- function() plot(1:20)
```

When you call `source('bar.r')`, the plot is not shown.  You can display it at your convenience by typing `bar()` at the command prompt.

Comment: Hi Richie, thank you so much for the link to what Dante would have written had R been around in the days :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might be of some help...

"A package that provides a null graphics device; includes a vignette, "devNull", that documents how to create a new graphics device as an add on package. "

from http://developer.r-project.org/